# Shell - diff between files and parameters in each line

Tags: php, bash, shell, diff, comm

I am looking for advance two file compare shell/bash/php. Let say i have such files:

file1

```
.run file=test_script.sql rev=1.1
.run file=test_sql.sql rev=1.1
.run file=test_drop.sql rev=1.2
```

file2

```
.run file=test_drop.sql rev=1.2
.run file=test_grant.sql rev=1.1
.run file=test_script.sql rev=1.2
```

get the difference between those files (ignoring line order) that is

```
.run file=test_grant.sql rev=1.1 #(because new line wasn't in file1 at all)
.run file=test_script.sql rev=1.2 #(because rev changed from rev=1.1 to rev=1.2)
```

but that is not all, i want to check if there was same (.run file=name) in the old file and if it was then get it's (rev=number). So that the final output will look like this:

file3:

```
 test_grant.sql 1.1 1.1
 test_script.sql 1.1 1.2
```

so far:
`fgrep -x -v -f file1 file2`

gets

```
.run file=test_grant.sql rev=1.1
.run file=test_script.sql rev=1.2
```

Comment: not much:
fgrep -x -v -f file1 file2

gets
`.run file=test_grant.sql rev=1.1`
`.run file=test_script.sql rev=1.2`

Comment: Are the `file` arguments unique within each file?

Comment: yes they are unique, in the same file it can't be file= with the same name

Comment: Why do you ignore the fact that `test_sql` was removed?

Comment: At this point i don't need info on what was removed only added newly or changed. It will make the end output even more complex cause i will do further jobs on information collected. Unless it would save in separate files let say to one file what was added and changed only e.g: file_added_modified:  `.run file=test_grant.sql rev=1.1 .run file=test_script.sql rev=1.2 `, and file what was removed eg.: file_removed: `.run file=test_sql.sql rev=1.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` script should do what you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {
    map[$2]=$3
    next;
}

!map[$2] || (map[$2] != $3) {
    sub3=substr($3, index($3,"=")+1)
    subm2=substr(map[$2], index(map[$2],"=")+1)
    print substr($2, index($2,"=")+1), subm2?subm2:sub3, sub3
}' file1 file2
```

While looking at the first file (`NR==FNR`) store the `rev` field in the `map` array under the `file` key.

While looking at the second file (the second block) if the `file` field in this line isn't in the `map` array or the current `rev` field doesn't match the matching `rev` field then print the current line.

To handle lines that were removed you would want to add `{delete map[$2]}` after the second block and then add `END {for (rev in map) {print "Missing: .run "map[rev]" "rev}}` to the end.

Comment: Nice, although the diff report would imply something like `print $2, map[$2], map[$3]`, except deleting up to `=` in each value. Side note: the idiom `FR==FNR` is really accident-prone because it will recognize the second file if the first file happens to be empty. `ARGIND==1` doesn't work either, because `ARGIND` counts non-file arguments like `V=1`. Personally, I prefer `ENDFILE{++files}` which lets you use `files` as a reasonably robust indicator.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong. It was the place where OP says "So that the final output will look like this:..."

Comment: @rici Yeah, I almost mentioned that `NR==FNR` has problems with empty files but didn't want to get into a whole discussion about how there isn't a non-GNU `awk` way to do it that is reliable. I haven't updated to think about `ENDFILE` yet since most of my `awk`ing is on CentOS 5 (awk 3.1.5) which doesn't have it but yes, that's a nice idiom. I hadn't noticed that about `ARGIND` that's annoying.

Comment: @rici Oh, wow, I totally skipped that block. Updating, thanks.

Comment: If you have ARGIND but not ENDFILE (both are gawk extensions, so there are no guarantees), you can still do it but its ugly (you have to manually check to see if arguments match the var=value syntax). Without either, it's really annoying because checking against FILENAME fails when files are repeated, but it can still be accomplished using a combination of that and the FNR==NR test. CentOS-- imho.

Comment: @rici CentOS 7 finally comes mostly into the modern era and includes gawk-4.0.2 (CentOS 6 is only awk 3.1.7).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also realised that i need small change - if `file=` wasn't listed in `file2` then instead of taking it's revision twice i need hardcoded  first entry `1.1` so just added it there: `awk 'NR==FNR {map[$2]=$3; next;} !map[$2] || (map[$2] != $3) { sub3=substr($3, index($3,"=")+1); subm2=substr(map[$2], index(map[$2],"=")+1); print substr($2, index($2,"=")+1), subm2?subm2:'1.1',sub3}' file1 file2`

Comment: So i figured out that i need removed files after all. Came up with this, it will put `rev=0` this i will know that it was removed. Don't know if it's grammatically correct but at least works :)
`awk 'NR==FNR {map[$2]=$3; next;} !map[$2] || (map[$2] != $3) { sub3=substr($3, index($3,"=")+1); subm2=substr(map[$2], index(map[$2],"=")+1); print substr($2, index($2,"=")+1), subm2?subm2:'1.1',sub3}{delete map[$2]}END {for (rev in map) {rmsubrev=substr(rev,index(rev,"=")+1); rmsubmrev=substr(map[rev],index(map[rev],"=")+1); print rmsubrev,'0',rmsubmrev;}}' file1 file2` @EtanReisner thanks again